# Key Bindings Not Working? How to Configure

Tags: emacs, octave

I'm using Emacs 24. and Octave 3.6.3 on Linux Mint Maya

I have set-up my init file, and all works fine. M-x run-octave gives me inferior octave, and .m files open automatically in octave mode.

But I can't seem to get key bindings to work? When I'm in octave mode, I press
'Ctrl' and 'c' together, then I press 'i', and emacs tells me that C-c i is undefined?

Could someone please help? I just want to send lines easily

Comment: Others have pointed out the correct keybinding, but I thought I'd mention that all bindings of the form C-c <letter> are reserved for the user (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).  Any mode that binds keys like this is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to look in the source file. Here is how shortcuts are defined for the octave mode:

```
(defvar octave-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "`" 'octave-abbrev-start)
    (define-key map "\e\n" 'octave-indent-new-comment-line)
    (define-key map "\M-\C-q" 'octave-indent-defun)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-b" 'octave-submit-bug-report)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-p" 'octave-previous-code-line)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-n" 'octave-next-code-line)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-a" 'octave-beginning-of-line)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-e" 'octave-end-of-line)
    (define-key map [remap down-list] 'smie-down-list)
    (define-key map "\C-c\M-\C-h" 'octave-mark-block)
    (define-key map "\C-c]" 'smie-close-block)
    (define-key map "\C-c/" 'smie-close-block)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-f" 'octave-insert-defun)
    ;; FIXME: free C-h so it can do the describe-prefix-bindings.
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-h" 'info-lookup-symbol)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-il" 'octave-send-line)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-ib" 'octave-send-block)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-if" 'octave-send-defun)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-ir" 'octave-send-region)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-is" 'octave-show-process-buffer)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-ih" 'octave-hide-process-buffer)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-ik" 'octave-kill-process)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-l" 'octave-send-line)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-b" 'octave-send-block)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-f" 'octave-send-defun)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-r" 'octave-send-region)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-s" 'octave-show-process-buffer)
    ;; FIXME: free C-h so it can do the describe-prefix-bindings.
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-h" 'octave-hide-process-buffer)
    (define-key map "\C-c\C-i\C-k" 'octave-kill-process)
    map)
  "Keymap used in Octave mode.")
```

As you can see, you have to use `C-c C-i l` to send a line

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation you read for `octave-mode` is outdated. You probably need to use `C-c C-i` as a prefix instead of `C-c i`. To have a full command you need to type another character, for example `r` or `C-r` to send the region.

This change was most likely done to conform with emacs specifications. Emacs reserves the keys in `C-c <char>` where `<char>` is any one character for the user. Therefore `octave-mode` should not have use such a key in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

disable some minor mode,maybe has some code defined likes`(define-key xx-map "\C-c i" nill)` and effected by mode-hook